# How to Create multiple folders each with multiple sub-folders

Tags: command-line

Is there a way of doing this at the terminal? i.e. without writing a script, e.g.

```
mkdir subject{1,2,3,4}/book{1,2,3}
```

why doesnt the preceeding work with or without the -p option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with following command:

```
mkdir -p Subject{1..4}/Book{1..3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following command and it worked:

```
mkdir mainfolder/{folder1/{subfolder,subfolder,subfolder},folder2/{subfolder,subfolder}}
```

That creates a "mainfolder" which contains two folder(folder1 and folder2) and their respective subfolders.